# Is there a way to uniquely identify a nested row in Tabulator without using the row index?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

When using the tree structure for nested data, I want to be able to identify which row a button is clicked from. Using `row.getPosition` only works for non-nested rows and returns -1 for a nested row. The data I am using also does not have an identifier field I can easily use so the `row.getIndex` function can't be used. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question (without a jsfiddle example), I think you can use the cellClicked callback to get access to the cell, and then the row for where the event occured.

Comment: Wouldn't that fire when the cell is clicked as well, not just when the button inside the cell is clicked?

Comment: Yes, but in the cellClicked callback, you can look at the Event parameter passed and see who the target of the click was, and if wasnt your button (or was you button, depending on how you want to handle the flow) you can decide what to do